# 'from main import db' gives ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'main'

Tags: python-3.x, flask, sqlite, flask-sqlalchemy

I created an SQLite3 database, called page.db.

I am trying to use it in python.

```
from flask import Flask
from flask_sqlalchemy import SQLAlchemy
import sqlite3

app=Flask(__name__)
app.config['SQLALCHEMY_DATABASE_URI']="sqlite:////mnt/home/cc/page.db'
db=SQLAlchemy(app)
class tabb(db.Model):
name=db.Column(db.Username,primary_key=True)
```

After writing this code, I enter python shell and run the command `from main import db`. It shows an error saying:

```
ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'main'
```

How can I fix this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Are you sure the filname is main and that you are in the same directory as main.py when opening the python interpreter?

Answer (score 0):

open terminal and then cd (projectname), after try again